# I lost bottom and side scroll bars in my logic editor

Tags: command-line

rel 2.70 in Blender Game mode
I lost bottom and side scroll bars in my logic editor panel
Can anyone help a Newbie? thx.

Comment: Could you upload a .blend where this is occurring? This will help us narrow down whether it's an issue with your setup/version of blender or a setting.

Comment: I placed the .blend thats missing scroll bars at github.com/marvosh/a_blend_test although I found a solution; when I eliminated all the windows but one, I rebuilt my GUI with the one that was a 3D window to start with. This caused the trouble. Now note if you create a layout from Game Logic you get a special window that has Templates - you cannot access this window type from Editor type. So to make a long story short I rebuilt my windows from this window and everything works.

Comment: Glad you got it working :) It seems to me like this should work though, you might want to file a bug report..